# Calculate start and end date for the given week number in particular month in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to calculate start date and end date for the particular given week in the month , (assuming my week starts on monday and ends on sunday).

So, What I want is if I select any week number lets say 1,2 ,3 or 4 I should be able to calculate the start date for that particular week and end date .
In addition to the week number for that particular month , I will also give an input of year and month.

selection of year month and week number will be from HTML page through a drop down select option.

And I am looking for some efficient way of doing this .

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I am new to angular so didn't do much , that is why I am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Moment.js
Get the value of week number

var weeknumber = moment("07-27-2017", "MM-DD-YYYY").week();    console.log(weeknumber);

Comment: I want the reverse of this , that is , I have a week number and I want the start date and end date of that week